# How to remove docker package from apt update?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, docker, kubernetes

On **Ubuntu 20.04** I had problems installing `minikube` due to some `docker` issues, so I decided to update it, but `sudo apt update` outputs **docker** package error:

```
Err:18 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease
    403  Forbidden [IP: 13.33.240.69 443]
```

So I decided to remove it, but first identifying what exact docker packages I have (docker-EE? docker-CE? docker? ...):

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
    rc  docker.io                                        19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04.2              amd64        Linux container runtime
    ii  python3-docker                                   4.1.0-1                               all          Python 3 wrapper to access docker.io's control socket
    ii  python3-dockerpty                                0.4.1-2                               all          Pseudo-tty handler for docker Python client (Python 3.x)
    ii  wmdocker                                         1.5-2                                 amd64        System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications
```

And then:

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose docker.io python3-docker python3-dockerpty
sudo apt purge -y docker.io
```

But `sudo apt update` still displays **... 403  Forbidden ...** error. How to can I make my system to completely forget about **docker** to proceed with new installation?

Comment: Have you removed the docker entry from your source list?

Comment: @Eagle_Mike no I haven't. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed the `repository` or `convenience script` method ([the first in this site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/))

Do :

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

and then rerun `sudo apt update`